# International transit at Xi'an Airport with Hainan Air

Tags: transit, china, layovers

I have a flight from Paris to Melbourne with an 11 hour layover in Xi'an airport. The carrier is Hainan Air.

- What is the procedure for transferring at Xi'an airport?
- I believe I have to get a 24-hour transit without visa (TWOV) stamp when going through immigration. Is there a special line for this?
- The airline offers accommodation for layovers longer than 6 hours. Is the accommodation at the airport?

Answer (score 1):

Points 1 & 2 are linked together. You go through immigration at a special counter for visa-exempted travellers. You have to notify the airline at check-in time that you don't have a visa and want to use the 24-hour TWOV facility.

Then you are out of the airport. You'll need to check in again for your next flight.